# Install Gnu/Linux on Ubiquiti Radio Device

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt, dd-wrt, ubiquity

good time

Can I install Linux on UBNT Radio ? (for example : Nano Station, Nano Bridge, AirGride)

Is there anyway to install Linux on this device ?

Linux OS or at least frimware(linux Base that could install MTR,SSH,WebServer,Mail Server)

thank you
Best Regards

Comment: IMHO this is too ambitions wish. The processor of Nano Station is 32bit, 400MHz, have 32MB of RAM. And as you have 8MB of flash where you will store the mails?

Comment: At least the Ubiquiti WiFi APs already run Linux. But like Romeo Ninov stated above, the processor of the device is chosen to fit the needs of its designed role, so there is unlikely to be very much unused capacity in the device. Also, since Ubiquiti seems to use MIPS processors in their products, you would need to find (or cross-compile) a MIPS version of any software you'd want to run: normal x86 or ARM software packages won't run on a MIPS processor at all.